# Why does Dropbox fail with a "dropboxd not found" error?

Tags: server, dropbox

This is a fresh install of Dropbox on a 12.04 server running on a 32bit system. It does not seem to fail the installation, but when I try to run it, I am told it can't find the file.

Following the instructions on the [Dropbox site](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx), I get the following message:

> ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd: 10: exec: ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: not found

Has anyone had this problem and know a work around? Running 12.04 server

Comment: Why didn't you install it from the software center?

Comment: Running 12.04 server, must have got cut in the edit.

Comment: @Kevin, nope, you haven't mentioned "server" on the question body, nonetheless, it is clear by the tag being used ;)

Comment: Are you using `mhddfs` ?

Comment: @Zuul, yea wasn't there. Thanks for the edit, much clearer.

Comment: @Zuul, not using mhddfs.

Comment: @Kevin, is the home dir `/home/kevin` encrypted?

Comment: FWIW, the problem appears not to be dropboxd (dropbox demon, the server); dropboxd is complaining that it can't find dropbox, which should be in the same directory.  But those permissions are not right - did you change them?  Should be -rwxr-xr-x, although that's not the problem.

Comment: @Zuul, not encrypted either.

Comment: @Marty Fried, it was giving me these problems when the permissions were set at -rwxr-xr-x, there was a suggestion on the Dropbox forums about changing the permissions but it still did not work

Comment: You are the owner of your home directory, so the permissions for other users makes no difference.  But it won't hurt, except for the colors in the bash terminal, which is only important to some of us. :)  But, do you have dropbox, the program, in that directory?

Comment: @Marty Fried, It should install dropbox into this directory, I don't get any errors during installation.  This is the same install procedure I have done on my 64-bit machine, and another 32-bit yet this one does not want to work.

Comment: Yes, but the error message is "/home/kevin/.dropbox-dist/dropbox: not found", so it would seem that either that file is not present, or it is not executable by you, or there is something wrong with the file, such as corruption.

Comment: @MartyFried, then it must be a corrupt file because dropbox is in the directory

Comment: FYI, I discovered this old computer I was using is capable of 64 bit instructions so I reinstalled with a 64bit OS and installed dropbox fine as per the instructions.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it, to help clean up the site a bit. Thanks! :)

Comment: @SirCharlo, The only solution I could find was to get a 64-bit computer.  I might play around with another 32-bit computer and see if I can get it fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure you installed the right dropbox architecture binary?

- [32bits version](http://www.dropbox.com/download/?plat=lnx.x86)
- [64bits version](http://www.getdropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

try use this /home/user/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd start

Comment: Please be more elaborate in your answer and explain why you think this solves the issue in the question.

Comment: I eventually got it to work after trying a few more times.  It might have been the wrong architecture.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to run dropbox using `/usr/bin/dropbox`
I installed the application while logged in as root.
Probably this is the reason `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`  and 
`/home/{user}/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` were not working.

Comment: Please restructure your answer.